# Reusing UITableViewCell with GCD

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) to load images of a `UITableViewCell` asynchronously. This works well except in some border cases in which the cell is reused, and a previous block loads the wrong image.

My current code looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *imagePath = [self imagePathForIndexPath:indexPath];         
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.imageView.image = image;
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
        });
    });

    return cell;
}
```

As far as I know GCD queues cannot be stopped. How can this border case be prevented then? Or should I be using something else instead of GCD to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm using GMGridView to show very large amount of image thumbnails and having the exactly same issue with it. I'm also using GCD to load thumbnails from my webserver on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what i've done is added an `NSOperation` ivar to the cell. the operation is responsible for getting, loading, and creating the image. when completed, it pings the cell. when/if the cell is dequeued, the operation is cancelled and destroyed if it has not finished. the operation test for cancellation when in `-main`. after the image is passed to the cell, the cell drops the operation and uses the image.

Comment: NSOperation is surely better than GCD, is usually use it, and putting it inside the cell is surely the best (and most elegant) way... +1

Answer (score 1):

You may try to force a reset of your image before you start your async request.

As user scroll the table, he may see the old image before your async method changes it with the right one

just add this line:

```
cell.imageView.image = nil; // or a placeHolder image
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image = image;
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

@hgpc:

> I don't think this solves the problem. A previous block can still set
>   the wrong image before a new block. – hgpc 9 mins ago

You're right, if user scroll fast this may be a problem...

the only way i see is to make a custom cell with a counter property where to store (in a sync way) the number of operationn in queue of each cell, and then in the async method check that the counter is == 1 before to change the image:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
    // MyCustomUITableViewCell has a property counter
            cell = [[[MyCustomUITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            cell.counter = 0;
        }

        NSString *imagePath = [self imagePathForIndexPath:indexPath];         
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

        cell.imageView.image = nil; // or a placeHolder image
        cell.counter = cell.counter + 1;
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (cell.counter == 1){
                    cell.imageView.image = image;
                   [cell setNeedsLayout];
                }
                cell.counter = cell.counter - 1;

            });
        });

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem. A previous block can still set the wrong image before a new block.

Comment: As it is now, the counter makes sure that only one image is set, but not necessarily the right one. Based on @willy's suggestion, I think you could simply set the view tag with the indexPath and check if it's the same before changing the image.

Comment: well, i guess the queue starts operation in the order you put them in queue, so the last one is the right one...  for willy answer, i'm not sure that in the async method you can still check in the indexPath is the correct one, it may store the old indexPath, the one that the cell had when the operation was started... you may make a test... let me know if it works, i'm really courious

Comment: +1 You're right. Since this is a global queue, the blocks will be processed in order.

Comment: Storing the indexPath.row in the cell tag and then checking if it's the same works. A bit hackish, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a cell identifier before launching the asynchronous task, and check it's the same before updating the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of possibilities here.

a) Use `NSOperationQueue` instead of direct GDC.
NSOperation is based on GDC and enabled a lot of management like stoping threads.
Take a look at the [concurrency guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091) from apple.

b) Use a ready async image loader.
There are enough free and open source project available on the internetz.
I personally recommend `AFNetworking` (particularly the `AFNetworking+UIImageView` category) for that.

If you want to do it on your own (research, knowledge, etc.) you should stay with **a)**, but the more convenient method is **b)**.

**Update**
I just noticed, that you are loading the image from a file and not from network.
In this case, you should handle it differently and take care at following points:

- Avoid `imageWithContentsOfFile:` and rather use `imageNamed:`. This is because `imageNamed:` caches your images once they where loaded and `imageWithContentsOfFile:` don't. If you need to use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` preload all images in a NSCache and populate the table with images from this cache.
- TableView images shouldn't be large in size (dimension **and** filesize). Even a 100x100 px retina image doesn't have more than a couple of kb which definitely don't take so long to load that you would need an async load.

Comment: It should be noted that the image is being loaded from a file, and that's the lag I want to make async. No download involved.

Comment: Ah i see, yes. But in that case you have other problems. I'll up my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

What about only loading the images when the table is not scrolling? The problem with `cellForRowWithIndexPath:` is that you're doing a lot of work for cells that are being scrolled past.

Instead of loading images whenever cells are dequeued, you could do it on `viewDidLoad` (or whenever your data model is initialized), and on `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initializeData];
    [self loadVisibleImages];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.tableView) {
        [self loadVisibleImages];
    }
}

-(void)loadVisibleImages {
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [self.tableview indexPathsForVisibleRows]) {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            NSString *imagePath = [self imagePathForIndexPath:indexPath]; 
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];        
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.imageView.image = image;
                [cell setNeedsLayout];
            });
        });
    }
}
```